# Python Instance, two independent classes

Tags: python, class, instance

I have two classes :

```
Class A  fileA.py  

Class B  fileB.py
```

On `fileB.py` I imported `fileA.py`

On `fileA.py` I create my `obj=ClassA()` and do stuff with methods.

Class A and Class B are comunicated each other by messages,topics etc

My problem is when I working on `fileB`, I want to work with the same object that I created on `fileA:  obj=ClassA()` and not a new one.

Comment: When you say "On `fileA.py` I create my `obj=ClassA()`", where is that code? Is it in a function? In a block guarded by `if __name__ == "__main__"`? Or just at the top level? If the latter, you can just use `classA.obj` in `classB.py` (after `import classA`) and it should work. If you create `obj` somewhere else, you'll need some other solution (and I can't guess what it would be without knowing more about the situation).

Answer (score 0):

The generic answer depends a lot on the specifics of what is done in both modules.

In your case, given the information you've given, I believe that you could simply:

- either have the `obj` global to the module,
- or create a function in `fileA` that would return the correct instance.

In any case, I believe you should think about the architecture of you system. If `fileA.py` is there to define class `A` modules define classes, why do you create a specific instance of this class in it? Why not creating this instance in `fileB.py` or even a third file that would use both classes?

Comment: The reason is that I'am using GUI(slave) and a ROS node (master). 
If I change some global variable in each file i need to update it.

Before, I used get and set methods but no solved it.

Comment: You don't want to try to change a global variable between two different processes (I assume you're not using nodelets). If you're talking about parameters, you should take a look at [dynamic reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure).